# How can a pathogenic bacterium be avirulent?

Tags: microbiology, infection, pathogenesis

*Streptococcus pneumoniae* R6 is a pathogenic bacterial strain but it is avirulent. How can a pathogen be avirulent. What does it mean if a pathogenic bacterium is avirulent?

Answer (score 3):

*Streptococcus pneumoniae* is a pathogenic species. *Streptococcus pneumoniae* R6 is an avirulent strain of this species. Presumably this means that specific virulence genes that are present in virulent strains of *Streptococcus pneumoniae* are missing or mutated in the R6 strain. In fact the most likely difference would be that virulence factors are encoded by a plasmid that has been lost in the avirulent strain.

The use of avirulent strains is a common strategy for studying pathogenic bacteria, although obviously it precludes studying mechanisms of pathogenicity directly.

Comment: Details as to what render the strain avirulent detailed [here](http://www.uniprot.org/proteomes/UP000000586). Namely, the lack of a capsule.